# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\)

Tags: java, escaping

I'm learning java and try example of Stack. This is code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class StackTry {

static boolean checkParity (String expression,
                            String open, String close) {
Stack stack = new Stack();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (expression, " \t\n\r\+/-(){}", true);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
String tmp = st.nextToken();
if (tmp.equals(open)) stack.push(open);
if (tmp.isEmpty()) return true;
return false;
}
public static void main (String [] args) {
System.out.println (
checkRarity("a - (b - (c - a) / (b + c) - 2), "(", ")));
}
}
}
```

I get error on 7 line, how to fix it?

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

I edited code as was adviced, but get

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method checkRarity(String, String) is undefined for the type 
 StackTry
- Syntax error on token ""a - (b - (c - a) / (b + c) - 2), "", , expected after 
 this token
```

Comment: See also _Escape Sequences_ in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: The error has nothing to do with using a stack, and the answer to your question is contained in the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because of the `\+`.

In Java anything beginning with `\` is treated as the beginning of a escape sequence and `\+` is not a valid escape sequence. Drop the `\` as you don't have to escape the `+`.

Answer (score 2):

In your string it seems you are trying to escape `+` sign, You don't have to do that and that is why you are getting the error. It should be like:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (expression, " \t\n\r+/-(){}", true);
```

You can specify `+` directly, if you are trying to provide backslash in the `StringTokenizer` then you have to use double backslash `\\`